# How would I make a Java class thread safe for XPages

Tags: java, xpages

I was writing (re-writing from LS) a Java library of common functions, for example, a method to add a user to a group in the Domino directory. In LotusScript this was done in an agent/script library and concurrent agents were not turned on. So, I did not have to worry about save conflicts if two users invoked the method to add a user to the same group.

In XPages they can run concurrently. So, I was wondering what is the best practice to restrict the method so it was thread-safe. I was initially thinking I was not going to use managed beans since I am not saving any information, just calling this method to add a user to a group. But, I can see that if the method was run concurrently to add a user to the same group there might be a save conflict.

Any suggestions on how to best prevent this? Use an application scoped managed bean and set a flag when the method is running? Or should I just handle this by calling save(false, false) so my document save will fail and I have logic in my code to try again? Or, is there some other best practice to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 approaches that come to my mind. First is to use the `synchronized` keyword to use Java's internal mechanism. This is perfectly fine when you don't expect much overlap but want a safeguard.

The second one would be more effort and only needed when there is a lot of concurrent action: instead of executing the action add it to a queue object and have a separate threat working through that queue.

You might want to read up on [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/)

Comment: So, just adding synchronized to my method (which would not see concurrent ops very often) would do it for multiple users of the same XPage for a plain old Java object (not a bean)? I know that works fine for Java programs but I was not sure of how each user spawns their own thread when they run the same XPage...

Comment: That's http servlet basics. Every request goes into its own thread

Comment: Yes, that is why I was asking if the synchronized will sync over the multiple threads spawned by XPages?

Comment: I added synchronized to the method "public synchronized static boolean  addUserToGroup(..". To test it I put in a sleep statement in the method as well as a print stmt at the start and end of the method. I then tried it from two different XPages in two different browsers, starting them right after each other. The second call to the method waited until it serviced the first XPage, proving it worked!!! Same result with the same XPage but different browsers.  Thanks Stephan!